# tracking users progress on web site

Tags: tracking, metrics, progress, logging

Short version:
I'm trying to determine the best way to track what the user does on our site. I.e., page they land on, what links they click, where they end up. Most of this information is stored in the log files, but is using the log file the best way for me to proceed?

Long version:
My boss is preparing to spend a lot of money advertising on multiple sites. He wants to know which ads perform the best, on which sites, and how long we retain our new visitors, if at all. That is, he's not satisfied simply knowing that our ad campaign brought in X new visitors, what he wants to know is where they came from, what they did, and if they bought anything.

As I said in the short version, I know that most of this is available in the log files, but is this the best way to go about it or should I use the backend php system to track this information and store it in the db in real time? Does there already exist a generally accepted method?

Tracking a user's progress is a topic that has always interested me, but until now I've never had the the time to delve into it. If anyone has some advice on even where to begin, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mint](http://haveamint.com/).

Forget GA, Webalizer, or AWStats.

Spend $30 on [Mint](http://haveamint.com/).
It does much more, more accurately than any competing product, is easy to use, and has great support.

And I don't even work there. :)

Some other products:

- [Crazy Egg](https://crazyegg.com/)
- [UserFly](http://userfly.com/)
- [ClickTale](http://www.clicktale.com/)
- [Loop 11](http://www.loop11.com/)

( 
These are far more useful than just garnering reams of raw data.
When used wisely, you can gain an entirely new level of understanding the user.
Each tool has a unique twist (though clicktale/userfly is similar), so it makes sense to use more than one.
)

Comment: It's a nice program, but I'm looking for something more advanced.

Comment: Curious - what was missing with mint?  (I've added links to two other sites).
My feeling with webalizer was that I could get more data, but it was less useful, even than GA.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to deploy a Web analytics product to your site.

Look at tools such as Google Analytics or AWStats. They will provide a reports with an analysis of the data collected by log files.

---

Comment: By web analytics, I assume you mean something more than Webalizer?